# Jpanel is not showing while running as a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am using below code running it as a thread from another File. ProgressBar is added to the frame in ProgressBarInit function which I am calling before starting thread frame is displayed from application but progressBar and progressLabel is not displaying. any help will be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class ProgressBar extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
   /**
    * 
    */
   private static ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -7461782745560910276L;
   private static final int MINIMUM_VALUE = 0;
   private static final int MAXIMUM_VALUE = 100;
   static public JProgressBar pbar;
   private static int totalProgress;
   private static int completedProgress;
   static JLabel progressLabel;
   JLabel spacer;
   static public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress....");
   static public JPanel panel = new JPanel();

   public static int getCompletedProgress() 
   {
      return completedProgress;
   }


   public static void setCompletedProgress(int completedProgress) 
   {
      ProgressBar.completedProgress = completedProgress;
   }


   public static int getTotalProgress() 
   {
      return totalProgress;
   }


   public static void setTotalProgress(int totalProgress) 
   {
      ProgressBar.totalProgress = totalProgress;
   }

   private ProgressBar()
   {
      //Empty Constructor
   }

   public static ProgressBar getInstance() 
   {
      return progressBar;
   }

   public void ProgressBarInit()
   {
      // initialize Progress Bar
      pbar = new JProgressBar();
      progressLabel = new JLabel("In Progress..");
      pbar.setMinimum(MINIMUM_VALUE);
      pbar.setMaximum(MAXIMUM_VALUE);
      pbar.setName("Progress");
      //pbar.setSize(10000, 1000);
      panel.setSize(300, 80);
      panel.add(pbar);
      //panel.add();
      panel.add(progressLabel);
      panel.setVisible(true);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setBounds(200, 200, 300, 80);

      frame.add(panel);
      //frame.add(progressLabel);
      frame.setResizable(false);
   }


   @Override
   public void run() 
   {

      frame.setVisible(true);
      while(getCompletedProgress()<=getTotalProgress())
      {
         int percent = getCompletedProgress()*100/getTotalProgress();
         pbar.setValue(percent);
         if(getCompletedProgress() == getTotalProgress())
         {
            break;
         }
      }
      frame.setVisible(false);
   }

   protected void updateBar(int newValue) 
   {
      pbar.setValue(newValue);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All interactions with swing components have to be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. Accessing swing compoments from other threads is not supported and will have all kind of nasty side effects.

If you want to execute something in an other thread have a looke at the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class. From the javadoc:

> An abstract class to perform lengthy GUI-interacting tasks in a
>   dedicated thread.
>
> When writing a multi-threaded application using Swing, there are two
>   constraints to keep in mind: (refer to How to Use Threads for more
>   details):
>
> Time-consuming tasks should not be run on the Event Dispatch Thread.
>   Otherwise the application becomes unresponsive.
>
> Swing components
>   should be accessed on the Event Dispatch Thread only.